# Is there a way to make android webview remember passwords?

Tags: c#, android, webview

Hi i made an android app that uses just a webview to look at my ip webcam, but my webcam asks username and a password everytime i open the app:
[image]

Is there a way to make android webviews remember those passwords, so i don't have to enter them every time?

I am using Visual studio, c# and Xamarin.

I should also mention, that i am new to programming especially on android, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `WebViewClient` class has a callback method `OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest` which is invoked by the `WebView` when the server wants a user name and password.  One of the parameters on this method is an `HttpAuthHandler` interface.  You control the authorization request by calling methods on this handler.

So the solution is to create a `WebViewClient` subclass that overrides `OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest` and calls the appropriate method on the `HttpAuthHandler`.  Then set your `WebView` to have an instance of this subclass.

Here's the link to the Xamarin documentation:  [OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebViewClient.OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest/p/Android.Webkit.WebView/Android.Webkit.HttpAuthHandler/System.String/System.String/)

```
    .
    .
    .
    var client = new MyWebViewClient();
    WebView web = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
    web.SetWebViewClient(client);
    .
    .
    .


class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient {

    public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm) {

        handler.Proceed(username, password);
    }
}
```